# Differentiation of an unitary operator in series expansion ( Quantum Mechanics )

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

This question is about series expansion of an unitary operator . Suppose we have an unitary operator $U(t,t_{o}) = exp(- i \int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt')$, where $H_{I}$ is the interacting Hamiltonian. Then, we expand $U(t,t_{0})$ into series

\begin{align}
U(t,t_{0}) &= exp(- i \int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt')\\
&=1 - i\int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt' + \frac{(-i)^{2}}{2}( \int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt')^{2} + ......
\end{align}

Then, we try to differentiate this with respect to t, and quadratic term gives us

\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{2}  \big(\int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt' \big)H_{I}(t) -\frac{1}{2} H_{I}(t) \big(\int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt' \big)
\end{align}
Where $H_{I}(t')$ and $H_{I}(t)$ are not commute

My difficulty is that I do not know how to derive the above equation. I tried to compute the differentiation of quadratic term

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \big( \frac{(-i)^{2}}{2}( \int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt')^{2} \big ) = (-i)^{2} \int^{t}_{t_{0}}H_{I}(t') dt' H(t)
\end{align}
Which is incorrect. Therefore, could someone point put the incorrect step in my derivation? Thank you

This problem is based on the [quantum field theory lecture](http://218.189.123.38/videoplayer/qft.pdf?ich_u_r_i=ae0ec302ddc29ba0f5395b9b2d980754&ich_s_t_a_r_t=0&ich_e_n_d=0&ich_k_e_y=1945088918751663592429&ich_t_y_p_e=1&ich_d_i_s_k_i_d=8&ich_s_e_q=670548826&ich_u_n_i_t=1) p.52

Comment: The link does not open.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that the link cannot be open. @Anonymous_orignal. You can go to this website and download this lecture note.   http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html

Answer (score 1):

For an operator $A(t)$ depending on time we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt} A(t)^2 = \frac{d}{dt} (A(t) A(t)) = \frac{d A(t)}{dt} A(t) + A(t) \frac{d A(t)}{dt} = A'(t) A(t) + A(t) A'(t)\,,
$$
where $A'(t)$ does not necessarily commute with $A(t)$. Thus you can NOT use the differentiation rule $\frac{d}{dt} A(t)^2 = 2 A'(t) A(t)$ when dealing with non-commutative objects.

Your problem corresponds to the case $A(t) =   \int_{t_0}^t H_I(t') dt' $.